Call REST service from Python Script
I am working on a project in Power Bi where we are supposed to select a record on a chart, read the selected record and get a key ID value from a column. That value needs to be used to pass it to a REST service which in turn returns data associated to the key that was selected. I have tried a few things:

Created a table in Power Query with a REST call. That works well and returns the data; but it is fixed to a Key ID only and have not found a way to refresh it at run time.

Wrote a Python script and I was able to make a call with Python to the REST service and retrieve the data; but again, with a fixed Key ID.

I have not tried to use DAX and I am not sure we can make REST service calls from DAX.


So, the question is, how can I make it dynamic? For that I would need to know what record was selected, read the column with the ID and pass it to the service call.
